# JSMP init command getting einval error

Tags: npm, cygwin, jspm

`jspm init` results in:

```
  Package.json file does not exist, create it? [yes]:
    err  Error: EINVAL, invalid argument
             at new Socket (net.js:157:18)
             at process.stdin (node.js:687:19)
             at MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\lib\ui.js:202:12
             at lib$rsvp$$internal$$initializePromise (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1084:9)
             at new lib$rsvp$promise$$Promise (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:546:53)
             at Object.exports.input (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\lib\ui.js:190:10)
             at Object.exports.confirm (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\lib\ui.js:157:15)
             at Promise.resolve.then.then.config.pjsonPath (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\lib\config.js:70:17)
             at tryCatchReject (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs\node_modules\when\es6-shim\Promise.js:1183:30)
             at runContinuation1 (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs\node_modules\when\es6-shim\Promise.js:1142:4)
             at Fulfilled.when (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs\node_modules\when\es6-shim\Promise.js:930:4)
             at ContinuationTask.run (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs\node_modules\when\es6-shim\Promise.js:1040:24)
             at Scheduler._drain (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs\node_modules\when\es6-shim\Promise.js:97:19)
             at Scheduler.drain (MY_FOLDER\aurelia\aurelia-typescript-simple\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs\node_modules\when\es6-shim\Promise.js:62:9)
             at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
             at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
```

Could be related to this: https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/610

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue could be related to my cygwin installation: [Node.js Cygwin not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043177/node-js-cygwin-not-supported)
Maybe it cannot enter the interactive prompt.

Using `jspm init -y` worked but it is not mentioned in most tutorials.